# Memoir ruled section centering problem

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, memoir

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\setaftersecskip{0em} 
\setsecheadstyle{\large \normalfont \bfseries \centering \MakeUppercase }
\setsecnumformat{  \csname  the#1\endcsname\par\nobreak \rule{\columnwidth}{0.2mm}  \par\nobreak }

\begin{document}
\section {Test Section}
\end{document}
```

The section title should be centered as the number.

May be `\centering` stops his effect after first `\par` (tried to change with `\\` but no effect) in `\setsecnumformat`, I don't know how to restore it or to make it effective for the whole title. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you are after.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}

\setaftersecskip{0em}
\setsecnumformat{\csname  the#1\endcsname\par\nobreak\vspace{-0.55\baselineskip} \rule{\columnwidth}{0.2mm}\par\nobreak }

\newcommand{\ruledsec}[1]{%
     \large \bfseries \centering \MakeUppercase{#1} \par\vspace{0.55\baselineskip}%
     }
\setsecheadstyle{\ruledsec}
\begin{document}
\section {Test Section}

Some text here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\nobreak` should be after `\par`, not after `\vspace`.

Comment: @egreg: I have to be careful but you know, I am not. :). Thanks.

Comment: wonderful! would you have also some explanation for it? why did you put the code for secheadstyle in a new command? many thanks

Comment: @peppino Actually you needed a `\par` after the section title  so that `\centering` is applied to the title too. The use of `\newcommand` made this possible. Also, the space after the title could be controlled easily this way. In a nut shell, the use of new command enabled us to use `\par\vspace{0.55\baselineskip}` after `\MakeUppercase{#1}`.